# how to control indeterminate progress bar in title when pressing back button and going to previous activity

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

So im trying to use a indeterminate progressbar in my custom title header to show any background work. Right now um using an asynctask to show and hide the progressbar using the pre and post methods:

Here's the class that contains everything:

> public abstract class QuadrosMobileActivity extends Activity{

```
protected static volatile ProgressBar progressHeader = null;
protected static int progressBarstate=ProgressBar.INVISIBLE;

//this method will launch respejcting oncreate logic for each activity 
public abstract void initActivity();


public int getProgressBarstate(){

    return progressBarstate;
}


public void setProgressBarstate(int state){

    progressBarstate=state;
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //set theme first for showing correct header
    setTheme(getThemeId());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //in case the screen will have a header
    if(getThemeId()!=R.style.CustomThemeNoHeader){

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(getLayoutId());

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_window_title);

        //set text header
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(getWindowTitle());

        progressHeader= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progresspinner);


        progressHeader.setVisibility(getProgressBarstate());

    }else   {
        setContentView(getLayoutId());
    }
    //execute activity logic
    initActivity();
}

private class ProgressBarThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressHeader.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        setProgressBarstate(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        updateResultsInUi();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressHeader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setProgressBarstate(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}
This is my main activity class where all my screen subactivities extend from.
The problem i have is, if i start the asynctask, the progressbar gets visible(all in Activity A) and while this happens if i go to another activity(B), the progressbar still appears correctly and gets hidden when the background work ends, all correct behaviour. BUT if i press the back button the previous activity(A) shows with the progressbar visible.
Here's a simple diagram:

**start Activity A:**

1. launches asynctask
2. shows progressbar
3. does background work

**go to Activity B:**

1. progressbar still shows
2. ends background work
3. hides progressbar  ***correct behaviour**

**go back to Activity A:**

1. progressbar is visible ***incorrect behaviour**
   ...

I tried this on the onResume method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(getThemeId()!=R.style.CustomThemeNoHeader){
        System.out.println("visible: " + ProgressBar.VISIBLE+" : " + getProgressBarstate());
        progressHeader.setVisibility(getProgressBarstate());

    };

}
```

But to no avail, can i really use the onResume to alter the progressbar state when pressing the back button???

Comment: Ok just tried on the onRestart method and changing the header text works but not the state of the progress bar???
 }

Answer (score 0):

This the method i tried:

```
@Override
public void onRestart () 
{
    super.onRestart();
    if (getThemeId() != R.style.CustomThemeNoHeader)
    {
    Toast.makeText(this, "visible(0): " + ProgressBar.VISIBLE+" : Current :" + getProgressBarstate(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // doesnt work
    QuadrosMobileActivity.progressHeader.setVisibility(getProgressBarstate());

    // works
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText("Tretas");
    }
}
```